# Как реализовать границу (пол) по которому персонаж передвигается 2D

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Вот пример того, что я имею ввиду:
[image: Изображение]

1 - собственно сама граница (пол), по которому должен передвигаться персонаж;
2 - персонаж;
3 - гора/лестница, всё что угодно подобного рода. Сама суть - персонаж должен подниматься по этому объекту (считай идти, просто высота объекта больше).

Я думал сделать это каким-то образом получая координаты (т.е., если на определённой высоте есть объект (1, 3), то персонаж должен передвигаться на чуть большей высоте)

Но выглядит это как-то затруднительно, учитывая величины координат (например, 900, 1042 и т.д.) и то, что ему придётся сканить каждый пиксель считай, может возможен какой-то более простой способ? Или может возможно поделить сам слой невидимой сеткой и получать уже координаты ячеек?

Answer (score 0):

Варианты:

1. Тест высоты и движение по пикселям.
2. Сделать сетку из квадратных блоков (например, размером 16х8 пикселей). И сделать тест высоты и движение по этим блокам. Считать что изменение высоты на 8 пикс персонах проходит, а 16 уже нет (только прыжком)
3. Сделать сетку из более крупных блоков разного типа - прямой, наклонный 45 градусов, наклонный 22,5. И сделать тест высоты и движение по блокам.
4. Сделать пол из геометрических фигур (прямоугольников, прямых и наклонных) и тест и движение вычислять геометрически.
5. Сделать полигональный пол и тест и движение вычислять геометрически.